# How to do joins with conditions?

Tags: sql, ms-access

I always struggle with joins within Access.  Can someone guide me?

4 tables.

```
Contest (id, user_id, pageviews)
Users (id, role_name, location)
Roles (id, role_name, type1, type2, type3)
Locations (id, location_name, city, state)
```

Regarding the Roles table -- type1, type2, type3 will have a Y if role_name is this type.  So if "Regular" for role_name would have a Y within type1, "Moderator" for role-name would have a Y within type2, "Admin" for role_name would have a Y within type3.  I didn't design this database.

So what I'm trying to do.  I want to output the following: user_id, pageviews, role_name, city, state.

I'm selecting the user_id and pageviews from Contest.  I then need to get the role_name of this user, so I need to join the Users table to the Contest table, right?

From there, I need to also select the location information from the Locations table -- I assume I just join on Locations.location_name = Users.location?

Here is the tricky part.  I only want to output if type1, within the Roles table, is Y.

I'm lost!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I can see, this is a query that can be built in the query design window, because you do not seem to need left joins or any other modifications, so:

```
SELECT Contest.user_id, 
       Contest.pageviews, 
       Roles.role_name, 
       Locations.city, 
       Locations.state
FROM ((Contest 
INNER JOIN Users 
ON Contest.user_id = Users.id) 
INNER JOIN Roles 
ON Users.role_name = Roles.role_name) 
INNER JOIN Locations 
ON Users.location = Locations.location_name
WHERE Roles.type1="Y"
```

Lots of parentheses :)

Comment: why are the parentheses required?

Comment: +1 for recommending using the Access query designer. Anyone who avoids it for no good reason is hampering their ability to get things done quickly.

Answer (score 1):

```
select * 
from users u
     inner join contest c on u.id = c.user_id and
     inner join locations l on l.id = u.location and
     inner join roles r on r.role_name = u.role_name
where r.type1 = 'Y'
```

This is assuming that location in users refers to the location id, if it is location name then it has to be joined to that column in locations table.

EDIT: The answer accepted is better, I did not consider that access needs parentheses.

Comment: This will not work in Access, there are no parentheses and Access is very fussy indeed about that.

Comment: I'd like to reiterate what @Remou said, that the best way to start queries like this for use in Access is to use the Access query builder. It takes care of all of this for you. I've never hand-written a join for use in Access, ever, and I've been programming in Access since 1996. I have often edited a join created by the QBE, but I never code it by hand.

Answer (score 0):

Can you show what query you are currently using? Can't you just join on role_name and just ignore the type1, type2, type3? I am assuming there are just those 3 role_names available.

Answer (score 0):

I know you didn't design it, but can you change the structure? Sometimes it's better to move to a sturdy foundation rather than living in the house that is about to fall on your head.

```
SELECT u.user_id, c.pageviews, 
IIF(r.role_Name = "Moderator", r.type1 = Y, 
IIF(r.role_name="Admin", r.type2="Y", r.type3="Y")), 
l.location_name FROM users as u 
INNER JOIN roles as r On (u.role_name = r.role_name) 
INNER JOIN contest as c On (c.user_id = u.Id) 
INNER JOIN locations as l On (u.location = l.location_name or l.id)
```

depending on whether the location in your user table is an id or the actual name reference.

Answer (score -1):

I think I need to see some sample data....I do not understand the relationship between Users and Roles because there is a field role_name within the Users table, and how does that relate the the Roles Table?

EDIT NOTE Now using SQL Explicit Join Best Practice

```
SELECT
    C.user_id
  , C.pageviews
  , U.role_name
  , L.city
  , L.state
FROM
    Contest C 
    INNER JOIN Users U        ON    C.user_id    =    U.id
    INNER JOIN Locations L    ON    U.location    =    L.id
    INNER JOIN Roles R        ON    U.role_name    =    R.role_name
WHERE
    R.type1='Y'
```

Comment: role_name from Users would link up with role_name from Roles.  So it's much like how user_id in Contest matches up with id from Users.

Comment: SELECT
   C.user_id
 , C.pageviews
 , U.role_name
 , L.city
 , L.state
FROM
   Contest C
 , Users U
 , Locations L
 , Roles R
WHERE
  C.user_id=U.id
 AND
  U.location=L.id
 AND
  U.role_name=R.role_name
 AND
  R.type1='Y'

Comment: Never use implicit syntax. It is a poor programming practice.